# Entity Framework Inserting Multiple Copies of Same Data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am having a strange problem with Entity Framework and SQL Server that I cannot figure out.

I am building an online store in ASP.NET MVC 5.

I am inserting statistics about a search into a table called SearchResults - it has this structure:

```
[SearchID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[SearchTerm] [varchar](5000) NULL,
[SearchDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Results] [int] NULL
```

I am just doing a simple EF insert with this C# code in the Search action of a controller, which gets posted to with a search term:

```
var s = new SearchResult() { SearchTerm = search, SearchDate = DateTime.Now, Results = results };
            db.SearchResults.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Results is an int with the count of the products found by the search.

Whenever I do a search, the same search gets inserted exactly 3 times, with slightly different times for each insert. The weird part is that occasionally, it will only insert one entry (as expected). I can't figure out why it is doing this.

I've run an SQL trace, and when it inserts 3, there is only one call to the DB. This is what is in the trace:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[SearchResults]([SearchTerm],[SearchDate], [Results])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [SearchID]
FROM [dbo].[SearchResults]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [SearchID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(5000),@1 datetime2(7),@2 int',@0='dew',@1='2015-02-16     16:32:53.4649185',@2=2
```

The weird part is the datetime shown in the insert is the value for the third insert.

I am at a complete loss for why this is happening. I've tried everything I can think of, but I am still getting repeats on insert.

Comment: Have any Triggers on the table?

Comment: No triggers or foreign keys. It's a standalone table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking at the wrong piece of code.
Had you logged or debugged the calls to the controller, how many times the first snippet of code you posted get executed?

Comment: Yeah, the more I test it, it seems something in the layout is triggering multiple calls. If I set the result page layout to null, I don't get the duplicated results. Thanks for the suggestion. I've not yet figured out what is triggering it though, it's a simple form post to a controller.

Comment: For reasons that make no sense to me, switching the search form from get to post as the method has caused the problem to go away.

Comment: That makes no sense.  You stated *there is only one call to the DB*, and changing a get to a post can not have that impact.

Comment: It makes zero sense to me either, but that single change has stopped the issue. I spent hours debugging, looking at the db traces, and never saw the repeated requests.